# Boost Websocket getting on_read: The WebSocket control frame was fragmented

Tags: c++, websocket, boost-asio

```
GET /socket.io/ HTTP/1.1
Host: <wss link> 
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Key: Z8W2ifsqt977ld8MkKNSiw==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
User-Agent: Boost.Beast/266 websocket-client-async-ssl
```

Sending above request on websocket but its failing in on_read with error "The WebSocket control frame was fragmented"
Using code from this link : https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/beast/example/websocket/client/async/websocket_client_async.cpp

Any Idea is it failing on client side or server side and is there any way to fix it?

```
 int main()
 {
 // Check command line arguments.
 auto const host = <wss link>;
 auto const port = "443";
 auto const text = {"token":"value1", "roomId":"value2"};

 // The io_context is required for all I/O
 net::io_context ioc;

 // Launch the asynchronous operation
 std::make_shared<session>(ioc)->run(host, port, text);

 // Run the I/O service. The call will return when
 // the socket is closed.
 ioc.run();

 return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In above link just one line change:
ws_.async_handshake(host_, "/socket.io/?
EIO=4&transport=polling",..... )

Comment: please show a [mre]. How are you sending the request? Have you tried using wireshark to intercept the traffic?

Answer (score 0):

The error code `beast::error::bad_control_fragment` indicated condition `condition::protocol_violation`:

```
/// Error conditions corresponding to sets of error codes.
enum class condition
{
    /** The WebSocket handshake failed

        This condition indicates that the WebSocket handshake failed. If
        the corresponding HTTP response indicates the keep-alive behavior,
        then the handshake may be reattempted.
    */
    handshake_failed = 1,

    /** A WebSocket protocol violation occurred

        This condition indicates that the remote peer on the WebSocket
        connection sent data which violated the protocol.
    */
    protocol_violation
 };
```

As the text indicates, it means your peer is not implementing the protocol as expected, or something else is interfering. This could be something to do with your code or the network transport between client and server.

Comment: GET /socket.io/ HTTP/1.1" 101 120 "-" "Boost.Beast/266 websocket-client-async-ssl".....this is on server side.
is socket.io and boost beast incompatible?

Comment: I don't think so. Adding self contained code will help to see what's going wrong

Comment: just using ws_.async_handshake(host_, "/socket.io/",.....), host = <wss link>, port = 443, and text as json = {"token":"<key1>", "roomId":<key2>}

Comment: Now getting "on_read:  stream truncated "when modified the part /socket.io/ to /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling

Comment: Please show the code. This is not helping me help you

Comment: Updated. Is above info ok?

Comment: @Inazuma No, but yes. Besides that none of that is valid code, you changed the port from 80 to 443. That implies that the server will speak HTTPS (HTTP over SSL). The client doesn't, so, yes, it will interpret the SSL protocol as if it were HTTP/Websocket and that cannot work for pretty obvious reasons. Start with this instead: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/beast/example/websocket/client/async-ssl/websocket_client_async_ssl.cpp